# Modifying the cursor of a resize grip in a WPF window ("CanResizeWithGrip" + "WindowStyle:none")

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, user-interface, xaml

Seems ilke none of the other StackOverflow questions answers this specific question. Or it may be lousy search skills...

I have a (*"`CanResizeWithGrip`" + "`WindowStyle="none"`"*) application written in `WPF` / `C#`.
The application resizes sideways only (*`MaxHeight` and `MinHeight` are the same*), so I would want the cursor of the `ResizeGrip` to be `ScrollWE` (*horizontal only*) instead of the diagonal default.
Users try to resize vertically when the cursor hints them they can.

I tried to modify the control template by using the code below, but then the whole window disappears and I'm left only with the resizegrip UI -- and still a diagonal cursor!

```
<Window.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
        <ResizeGrip Cursor="ScrollWE" />
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Template>
```

Resizing is working properly, the window is stylized properly (*when I don't use the `ControlTemplate` above*).
**I only need to change the cursor that appears over the `ResizeGrip`. How to do that?**

Hints on directions to follow are welcome too (*complete answers even more :)*).

---

**Edit:** Hans is right on his comment. I mistakenly used ScollSE in my ControlTemplate trial (I fixed that in the question now).

Comment: Can't make sense of this, ScrollSE is a *corner* cursor.

Comment: You are right Hans, fixed the question, and +1 in your comment...

Answer (score 3):

If I create a window with the following markup

```
<Window x:Class="PocketExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel>
        <ResizeGrip DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Cursor="SizeWE"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

I get the correct cursor. Does this not work for you? Are you *really* using a ScrollSE cursor? As Hans points out, that is a diagonal cursor which would explain why you're getting a diagonal cursor.

Comment: Yes, with a ScrollWE I still see the diagonal cursor when using the ControlTemplate.

Regarding your example, when I add a resizegrip of my own, how can I tie it to a resize of the window?
I use grids, so I adapted your example to
<ResizeGrip Grid.Column="3" Cursor="ScrollWE" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
(Column=3 is the last column).

It isn't resizing the window, maybe because it's working over the column only (which is, BTW, a fixed size column).
What happens, is that the window is dragged (moved).